# How to generate report as pdf in SonarQube V6.3.2?

Tags: pdf, plugins, sonarqube, report

Currently, I am using Sonarqube 6.3.2. I need to generate PDF. I have tried using some plugins, but they are not compatible with SonarQube 6.3.2.

Is there any other way to generate PDF reports in SonarQube 6.3.2?

Comment: what plugins you have already tried ? can u please mention that ?

Comment: @aksss,   i had tried sonar-pdf-report plugin by copy/pasting in to plugin folder. but no luck. This plugin is working fine in older version .

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no solution that we are aware of to generate PDF reports for projects.

The only plugin that generates PDF is [Governance](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/governance.html), but it does not feature the PDF generation at project level yet (only at portfolio level).

Comment: do u have any idea that will be getting this pdf generation option for new sonar version?